# Is there a way to copy pointers in C for linked lists?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, infinite-loop

I am implementing a linked list using C which has insertion functionality at the `head`, `tail` (last node), and at the `k`th index. When I try to implement the insertion functionality however, and try to enter more than 1 entry in the list, printing the elements enters an infinite loop. The nodes and insertion function is defined as:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct node{
        int val;
        struct node *next;
    };

struct node * insertathead(struct node * head,int ele,struct node * new){
    new->val=ele;
    new->next=head;
    return new;
}

int main(){
    struct node *head=NULL;
    struct node *tail=NULL;
    int len=0;
    while(1){
        int k=0,k1=0,ele;
        printf("Welcome to linked list interface!\nWhat would you like to do?\n1. Insert\n2. Delete\n3. Print all elements\n4. Exit\n");
        scanf("%d",&k);
        if (k==4){
            break;
        }
        switch(k){
            case 1:
                printf("Where would you like to insert? (Enter 0 or -1 for head or tail resp) : ");
                scanf("%d",&k1);
                if (k1>len){
                    printf("Index Error\n");
                    break;
                }
                printf("Enter the element: ");
                scanf("%d",&ele);
                struct node * k;
                struct node new;
                if (k1==0){
                    head=insertathead(head,ele,&new);
                        }
                len+=1;
                break;

            case 3:
                struct node *k2=head;
                if (len==0){
                    printf("Underflow\n");
                }
                else{
                while(k2!=NULL){
                        printf("\n%d\n",k2->val);
                        k2=k2->next;
                    }
                }
                break;

}
```

Upon compiling and inserting 2 at `head` and then 3 at `head` and then printing the list, the code goes into an infinite loop of printing 3. I suspect this has something to do with assigning the `new.next` as `head` and then updating `head` to be the address of `new`, however I can't seem to figure out how to fix this.

I tried to pass `&*head` instead of `head` in hopes to copy the pointer without updates affecting it instead, but it still resulted in the same output. I also tried using `*new.next=*head` but that did not affect it either. Googling results in no help, and in sample programs the same process seems to work.

Comment: maybe try to insert an element "between" `head` and `head->next`

Comment: Added a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: The `&new` you pass to the insetion function is a pointer to `new`, which is always the same node. You must, of course, add different nodes to the list. One way to get a fresh node is with `malloc`.

Comment: Using malloc instead of declaring struct node new fixed it. Thanks @MOehm.

Comment: It should not even compile